# Auto generate compound primary key spring jpa

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data

I wanna create a compound primary key, one field of which is autogenerated (JPA).
Can I do this ? Is it possible some how to get a generator from spring environment ?

My entity code is

```
@Entity
@IdClass(value = IntemKey.class)
public class Item implements Serializable {
    @Id // wanna autogenerate this field
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private Date add;

    private Date del;

   ....
   getter/setter
}


@Embeddable
public class ItemKey implements Serializable {    
    private Long id;
    private Date add = new Date();

    ...
    getter/setter + equals + hashCode  
}
```

table with data

- id  add                      del
- 1  2015.01.01   null
- 2  2015.01.03  2015.01.05
- 2  2015.01.05  null

Answer (score 1):

It can be created by Hibernate, check [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#d0e5294) for more information.

```
@Id // wanna autogenerate this field
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

***EDIT : *** For compound key check this [blog post](http://uaihebert.com/tutorial-jpa-composite-primary-key/)

Comment: You are right, but in my case this approach works for single primary key, not for a compound key

Comment: @moroI update my answer according to your requirement.